# Bug or Logical Error

Tags: java

I'm using Netbeans, and I've written a method that's not doing exactly what it should:

```
private ArrayList<String[]>ProductsInStock;

public void DisplayStock() {
    ArrayList<String[]> Sort = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < ProductsInStock.size(); i++) {
        if (ProductsInStock.get(i)[2].equals(Products.get(ProductCodeCB.getSelectedIndex())[1])) {
            boolean foundColor = false;
            int size = Sort.size();//Since the size will differ dynamically
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                if (Sort.get(k)[3].equals(ProductsInStock.get(i)[3])) {
                    foundColor = true;
                    if (Sort.get(k)[4].equals(ProductsInStock.get(i)[4])) {
                        String S[] = Sort.get(k);
                        S[5] = (Integer.parseInt(Sort.get(k)[5]) + Integer.parseInt(ProductsInStock.get(i)[5])) + "";
                        Sort.set(k, S);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (k == Sort.size() - 1) {
                        Sort.add(ProductsInStock.get(i));
                    }
                } else if (foundColor == true) {
                    Sort.add(k, ProductsInStock.get(i));
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(ProductsInStock.get(0)[5]+" ");
            if (foundColor == false) {
                Sort.add(ProductsInStock.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The method should NOT change the value of ProductsInStock.get(0)[5], yet it is incrementing it by 1 everytime the method is called, I've placed the "System.out.println()" to show you how the value is actually changing. Here are the results: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 
And when i added the line "S[5]=ProductsInStock.get(i)[5];", the result changed to: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 (as it should be):

```
public void DisplayStock() {
    ArrayList<String[]> Sort = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < ProductsInStock.size(); i++) {
        if (ProductsInStock.get(i)[2].equals(Products.get(ProductCodeCB.getSelectedIndex())[1])) {
            boolean foundColor = false;
            int size = Sort.size();//Since the size will differ dynamically
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                if (Sort.get(k)[3].equals(ProductsInStock.get(i)[3])) {
                    foundColor = true;
                    if (Sort.get(k)[4].equals(ProductsInStock.get(i)[4])) {
                        String S[] = Sort.get(k);
                        S[5] = (Integer.parseInt(Sort.get(k)[5]) + Integer.parseInt(ProductsInStock.get(i)[5])) + "";
                        Sort.set(k, S);
                        S[5]=ProductsInStock.get(i)[5]; //<<<<HERE>>>>
                        break;
                    }
                    if (k == Sort.size() - 1) {
                        Sort.add(ProductsInStock.get(i));
                    }
                } else if (foundColor == true) {
                    Sort.add(k, ProductsInStock.get(i));
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(ProductsInStock.get(0)[5]+" ");
            if (foundColor == false) {
                Sort.add(ProductsInStock.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is not a single "ProductsInStock.set()" or "ProductsInStock.get()[]= " to change any value in the arraylist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write this :

```
 Sort.add(ProductsInStock.get(i));
```

you are adding a reference of the `ProductsInStock.get(i)` array to the `Sort` list. Any changes done in `Sort.get(Sort.size()-1)` will affect the original array.

Therefore code such as

```
String S[] = Sort.get(k);
S[5] = ...
```

modifies one of the arrays of `ProductsInStock` List.

In order to avoid that, you should create a copy of your array before adding it to the other List :

```
Sort.add(Arrays.copyOf(ProductsInStock.get(i),ProductsInStock.get(i).length));
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh, now that is something they don't teach you everyday thanks allot!!! Btw do i always need to make a copy of an array (Example: int i [] =j where j is an another integer array)